# Sharing application scope data data between web applications?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, java-ee-6

I am using below to access the session data set by **App1** in **App2**.

### in App1:

```
ServletContext sctx = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getServletContext();
    String testStr = (String) sctx.getAttribute("attr");
    if(testStr == null){
        testStr = "test";
        sctx.setAttribute("attr", testStr);
    }
```

### in App2

I get session value as below.

```
ServletContext sctx = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getServletContext().getContext("/app1");
    String testStr = (String) sctx.getAttribute("attr");
    System.out.println("the value which set in first app: " + testStr);
```

Actually my `App2 will be in cluster environment`. In this case should **App1** will also be in cluster environment?
My App2 is a web application which has few web services exposed and it does not contain any UI. There must not be any direct communication between App1 and App2. App1 has to put some value in Application scope on its start up and later App2 should access application scoped value whenever is required. Thanx

Do i have any issues in cluster environment? Is my approach correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: @Markus, the link does not suit my need..Thanks!

Comment: The title is misleading. The `ServletContext` is not a session; this data is application-scoped.

Comment: Yes. You are Correct. In this case both App1 and App2 should be in same App server right?

Comment: If you want to share servlet context attributes then, yes, both apps must be running on each node in the cluster. If you want to replicate that data across the cluster I don't have any suggestions as I've never used Tomcat in this way.

Comment: Thanx much for ur reply...if there is any node changes the application scope variable value then will it reflect in all nodes? Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

1. Both applications are in a clustered environment
2. Everything in your session attributes are serializable
3. Your sessions are persisting some datastore shared by the cluster

Then your session attributes should be available across all servers.

Comment: Lane, Thanks for ur reply. If i dont keep App1 in Cluster environment then it wont work right ? Also Both App1 and App2 Should be in same application server right? Thanx

Comment: It depends on the servlet container.  I know JBoss will allow sharing sessions between web deployments, but to avoid implementation dependence, I'd suggest using one application.  Alternatively, you could store this information in a cookie.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply. I cannot use cookie mechanism as am not dealing with browser and it does not contain UI. But it is a web application. Here App2 has few web services exposed. Thanx